# Getting web app context information after project deployment without hitting web endpoint

Tags: servlets, initialization, jax-rs, contextpath

I have a package for internal use that when added to a project needs to send a notification to our QA application that it is live, and at what endpoint it is available. To that end, I need to get the context root of the project.

The problem
What I attempted first was the following:

```
@Path("/myEndpoint")
public class MyAPI {

@Context
ServletContext context

@Get
public MyObject getMyObject() {
    ...
    context.getContextPath(); // store path in MyObject
    return myObjectInstance;
}
```

The issue with this is that someone needs to hit the endpoint first in order to get the path info. I want something that will run when the project is deployed. My next attempt was to use `@Singleton` with `@PostConstruct`, but I didn't think it best practice to have my API class running that sort of code (and the ServletContext was null, so it wouldn't work even if I did opt to leave the code in...)

I've tried one or two other things, but to no avail. A suggestion in the department was to make a Maven plugin that would ping the QA server with that sort of information, but I'm hoping to find a Java solution for simplicity's sake. Is there another way to get access to the context root and have a method automatically fire after project deployment?

I am using Java8 with Maven, and our applications are deployed using Glassfish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, based on the lack of responses here, and after internal discussions, we will write a maven plugin that will handle the context and other information my service will need.